Rotating SDF rectangle with Matrix4
Hei
I'm trying to create my own UI renderer from scratch using SDF functions,
got it working pretty good without any transformations, but now I would like to add MAT4 transforms to the SDF calculations too, but I can't figure it out.
The vertex calculations are correct, but the SDF drawing is not matching the rotation.
Attached the screenshot describing how it's rendered.

Here's my GLSL code
Fragment
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_GOOGLE_include_directive : require
#extension GL_EXT_buffer_reference2 : require
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : require

#include "types.glsl"

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D materialSamplers[];

layout(location = 0) in vec2 widget_size;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 center_pos;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 tex_pos;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;


float roundedBoxSDF(vec2 center, vec2 size, vec4 radius) {
    radius.xy = (center.x > 0.0) ? radius.xy : radius.zw;
    radius.x  = (center.y > 0.0) ? radius.x  : radius.y;
    
    vec2 q = abs(center) - size + radius.x;
    return min(max(q.x,q.y),0.0) + length(max(q,0.0)) - radius.x;
}


float sdRoundBox( vec3 p, vec3 b, float r )
{
  vec3 q = abs(p) - b + r;
  return length(max(q,0.0)) + min(max(q.x,max(q.y,q.z)),0.0) - r;
}


void main() {
    CanvasBuffer canvas_item = canvas_buffer[draw_index];


    vec4 point = (canvas_item.transform * gl_FragCoord / vec4(resolution, 0.0, 1.0) - center_pos);

    float distance = 0;

    // distance = roundedBoxSDF(point.xy, widget_size, canvas_item.border_radius / 10.0);
    distance = sdRoundBox(point.xyz, vec3(widget_size, 1.0), 0.1);


    vec4 fillColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    vec4 color = fillColor;

    if (distance < 0) {
        color = canvas_item.texture_id > -1 ? texture(materialSamplers[canvas_item.texture_id], tex_pos) : canvas_item.color;
    }

    float border_size = canvas_item.border_width / 100.0;
    float borderAlpha = smoothstep(border_size - 0.002, border_size, abs(distance));
    float smoothedAlpha =  smoothstep(0.0, 1.0 / resolution.x, distance);

    vec4 widgerColor = mix(canvas_item.border_color, color, borderAlpha);

    outColor = widgerColor;
}

Vertex
#version 450
#extension GL_EXT_buffer_reference2 : require
#extension GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout : require
#extension GL_GOOGLE_include_directive : require
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : require

#include "types.glsl"

layout(location = 0) out vec2 widget_size;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 center_pos;
layout(location = 2) out vec2 texture_pos;

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D materialSamplers[];


// Default vertices, for drawing the SDF primitives on
vec2 vertices[6] = vec2[](
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 0.0)
);

void main() {
    CanvasBuffer canvas_item = canvas_buffer[draw_index];
    float scale = projection[0][0] - 2.0;

    vec2 vertex = vertices[gl_VertexIndex];

    vec2 corner = canvas_item.corner / resolution;
    vec2 size = canvas_item.size / resolution;
    vec2 vertex_pos = (vertex * size + corner);

    widget_size = size * (1.0 - scale);
    texture_pos = vertex;

    gl_Position = projection * view * canvas_item.transform * vec4(vertex_pos - scale, 0.0, 1.0);

    center_pos = projection * view * canvas_item.transform * vec4(corner, 0.0, 1.0) / 2  + vec4(widget_size, 0.0, 0.0);
}


Managed to fix it myself, got the SDF function working from vertex texture_pos and skipped using gl_FragCoord, made life much easier.
I still don't fully understand how SDF calculations work, glad it started working though.

Below is working code, when someone else also stumbles on same problem.
Vertex
layout(location = 0) out vec2 texture_pos;

vec2 vertices[6] = vec2[](
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 0.0)
);

void main() {
    CanvasBuffer canvas_item = canvas_buffer[draw_index];
    vec2 vertex = vertices[gl_VertexIndex];

    vec2 corner = canvas_item.corner / resolution;
    vec2 size = canvas_item.size / resolution;

    vec2 vertex_pos = (vertex * size + corner);

    gl_Position = projection * view * canvas_item.transform * vec4(vertex_pos, 0.0, 1.0) + vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

Fragment
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D materialSamplers[];

layout(location = 0) in vec2 tex_pos;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;


float roundedBoxSDF(vec2 center, vec2 size, vec4 radius) {
    radius.xy = (center.x > 0.0) ? radius.xy : radius.zw;
    radius.x  = (center.y > 0.0) ? radius.x  : radius.y;
    
    vec2 q = abs(center) - size + radius.x;
    return min(max(q.x,q.y),0.0) + length(max(q,0.0)) - radius.x;
}

void main() {
    CanvasBuffer canvas_item = canvas_buffer[draw_index];
    float border_size = canvas_item.border_width / 100.0;
    vec2 widget_size = vec2(0.5, 0.5) - vec2(border_size);

    float distance = 0.0;

    distance = roundedBoxSDF(tex_pos - border_size - widget_size, widget_size, canvas_item.border_radius / 10.0);

    vec4 fillColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    vec4 color = fillColor;

    if (distance < 0) {
        color = canvas_item.texture_id > -1 ? texture(materialSamplers[canvas_item.texture_id], tex_pos) : canvas_item.color;
    }

    float borderAlpha = smoothstep(border_size - 0.002, border_size, abs(distance));
    float smoothedAlpha = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0 / resolution.x, distance);

    vec4 widgerColor = mix(canvas_item.border_color, color, borderAlpha);

    outColor = widgerColor;
}

